# Multiselect value does not rendered all previously selected value

Tags: magento2, php

I add an admin grid using the below mentioned url. Now I add a multi-select field in the form by editing at `App/Code/Webkul/Grid/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/AddRow.php` file.It is visible fine. I use `implode() function` to convert the array into string and the value get stored at database as (1,3,5 ).But When I reopen the form by clicking on 'edit' option, form is loaded but in multiselect field only one value is selected. I need a help in this regard.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your codes with screenshot?

Comment: I use this link

Comment: https://github.com/webkulabhi/magento2-create-admin-grid-CURD-operations

Comment: Check my answer. Its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the following file:

> /app/code/Webkul/Grid/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Edit/Form.php

Add the below code

```
$alloptions = array(
                    array('label' => 'ABC1', 'value' => 'ABC1'),
                    array('label' => 'ABC2', 'value' => 'ABC2'),
                    array('label' => 'ABC3', 'value' => 'ABC3'),
                    array('label' => 'ABC4', 'value' => 'ABC4'),
                    array('label' => 'ABC5', 'value' => 'ABC5'),
                    array('label' => 'ABC6', 'value' => 'ABC6'),
                    );

$fieldset->addField(
    'name',
    'multiselect',
    [
        'label' => __('Service Name'),
        'title' => __('Service Name'),
        'name' => 'name',
        'values' => $alloptions
    ]
);
```

You can change the options and field name according to your requirement.

Also you need to change the below file:

> /app/code/Webkul/Grid/Controller/Adminhtml/Grid/Save.php

Add the below line:

```
$data['name'] = implode(',',$data['name']);
```

Just after the line:

```
$rowData = $this->gridFactory->create();
```

Like below:

```
$rowData = $this->gridFactory->create();
$data['name'] = implode(',',$data['name']);
$rowData->setData($data);
if (isset($data['id'])) {
    $rowData->setEntityId($data['id']);
}
$rowData->save();
```

Here I am using field name as "name". You need to create a field name called "name" in the table as well.

No need to change any other files.

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding.